# much longer VS. any longer

Tags: adverbs, intensifiers

> Neither sides is inclined to protract the dispute **much longer**; a settlement is expected presently.

I am wondering if we could replace *much longer* in the stand of *any more*.

Extracted from the book vocabulary for the high school student

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Want to ask about any longer or any more? Which word is replaced by which word?

Comment: Is your book this one: http://www.amazon.com/Vocabulary-School-Student-Norman-Levine/dp/1567651151? -- As for the replacing *much longer* with *any more*, you could, but the result would be not quite the same.

Comment: thanks. no it is " for the High School Student

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither sides is inlined to protract the dispute much longer/any longer/any more

As far as the phrases "any more" and "any longer" are concerned, they are interchangeable, without any difference in meaning.

As for the phrases "much longer" and "any longer/any more", though they can be used in the sentence, they are not interchangeable because they convey different senses.

If you wan to emphasize that neither sides is inclined to protract the dispute even to a small degree/in the least, you can use any more/any longer. On the other hand, the use of "much longer" in the sentence conveys the sense that either of the sides can stand the protraction of the dispute by a small amount/degree, but not to a greater amount/degree.

Comment: I don't agree that "any more" could fit into the example sentence because of the verb ["protract"](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/protract) which I think requires a duration like "longer". @nima